# How to store a PHP variable in SQL such that when retrieved it is still a variable (not a value)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to save a string in SQL such that each time it is called, part of the string is a variable. For example, if the string is "Hello my name is $name", I want to save it such that whenever it is retrieved, $name is still a variable:

```
$name = "Doug";
$row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query_result);

$message = $row['message'];  // "Hello, my name is $name."

echo $message;  // "Hello, my name is Doug."
```

One way would be:

```
str_replace('$name', $name, $message);  // called before echo
```

I've never been too comfortable with variable variables, but from what I understand, a general function for the str_replace method could be made using them.

My question is whether or not this is necessary? Is there a much easier way to store a variable in SQL and keep it variable?

Comment: Storing a literal `$var` is not a problem. Did you just forget to use single quotes to not get it interpolated prior insertion? Or is your question really about how to make the `str_replace` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it a format string for `sprintf`.

```
$name = "Doug";
$row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query_result);

$message = sprintf($row['message'], $name);  // "Hello, my name is %s."

echo $message;  // "Hello, my name is Doug."
```

Or `str_replace` as you said.

Comment: This approach is, to me, cleaner and more readily understood than using str_replace.  It's also more flexible, and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use eval() but I strongly suggest to *not* use it. Instead use a placeholder in your string and replace it when outputing, e.g. using [sprintf()](http://ch2.php.net/sprintf) or str_replace() as you suggest.

Comment: Eval does not make sense unless the string was stored as expression, that is `'"Hello, my name is " . $name'`

Comment: That's not true as you can, for example, `echo "Hello $world";`, too.

Comment: Which is a double quoted string expression, not literal text as received from the database.

Comment: eval() does "evaluate string as PHP code" and you can change the db result in any way you want it. For example see the example in http://ch2.php.net/eval .

Comment: addslashes() should avoid this problem. But anyway, it is *not* a good solution and as such should be avoided entirely.

Comment: I was under the impression you did "strongly suggest to not use it" only for the silly eval is evil / insecure meme. Explaining the extraneous effort to actually utilize it would have been a valid reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it at the query level using [`replace()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
//part of the query
$query .= "SELECT replace('message','\$name','{$name}')";
```